# adding more than one sources of data to angular

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

this is what I have in my model

```
// The contents of individual model .js files will be concatenated into dist/models.js

(function() {

// Protects views where angular is not loaded from errors
if ( typeof angular == 'undefined' ) {
    return;
};


var module = angular.module('myModel', ['restangular']);

module.factory('myRestangular', function(Restangular) {

  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {

    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://localhost/data');
    RestangularConfigurer.setRequestSuffix('.json');
    RestangularConfigurer.setRestangularFields({
      id: "my_id"
    });

  });

});


})();
```

this is fine. but now I have another json that I need to grab data from. How could I change this model to look for that other json as well. I am very very new to angular and still learning how model data binding works!

**This is what I have tired **

my model

```
var module = angular.module('FloorModel', ['restangular']);

module.factory('FloorRestangular', function(Restangular) {

    return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {

        RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://localhost/data/floor');
        RestangularConfigurer.setRequestSuffix('.json');
        RestangularConfigurer.setRestangularFields({
            id: "floor_id"
        });

    });

});


**my controller**


myApp.controller('FloorCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, FloorRestangular) {


    // Fetch all objects from the local JSON (see app/models/mdpocket.js)
    FloorRestangular.all('floor').getList().then( function(floors) {
        // Then select the one based on the view's id query parameter

        $scope.floor = $filter('filter')(floors, {floor_id: steroids.view.params['id']})[0];
    });

    // -- Native navigation
    steroids.view.navigationBar.show("Floor: " + steroids.view.params.id );

});
```

**my view **

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="FloorCtrl">
    <div class="topcoat-list__container">

      <ul class="topcoat-list">
        <li class="topcoat-list__item" hm-tap="open(floor.floor_id)" ng-repeat="floor in floors">
          Floor Name: {{ floor.name }}
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```